# "Отдать" и "передать" - синонимы?

Tags: стилистика

По разным словарям получается, что да. Но можно ли "передать" имениннику подарок, если он от тебя? Как-то звучит не очень. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОТДАТЬ кого-что. Передать кому-л., вручить; ПЕРЕДАТЬ кого-что. Отдать, вручить из своих рук что-л. кому-л.

Глагол "передать" используется в тех случаях, когда подчеркивается передача предмета из рук в руки, например:

Он перекрестился, положил полу своей шинели себе на руку, взял недоуздок и передал мне лошадь. Я рассказала свое дело, граф подтвердил еще раз, что он из рук в руки передал письмо государю об этом.Чайкин отпил из фляжки и передал ее Чезаре. Покупок было рублей на десять, но у капитана имелась только двадцатипятирублевая бумажка, которую он и передал денщику.

Можно представить такое предложение: "Он передал ей  подарок и быстро вышел".

Answer (score 4):

Это не синонимы, а однокоренные слова. Говоря юридическим языком, в случае с **отдать**, человек является дарителем, а с **передать** - посредником. Отдавая - отчуждаешь своё, - в этом процессе участвуют две стороны: дающая и принимающая. При передаче, помимо дающей и принимающей, появляется третья сторона - средство, проводник, через которую и происходит передача.

Answer (score 1):

Передать имениннику подарок  - можно. В прямом смысле этого слова. А передать подарок в смысле "подарить" некорректно.